# React: fetch call's then function not being called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch inside a render function and have a then function that does something. My code is below. However, it doesn't seem to ever call the then function.

```
fetch(url, {
          method: "GET",
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*", "Cache-Control": "no-store" },
          body: null
    })
.then(function (res) {console.log("here");finished++})
.catch(function (err) {console.log(err)});

while (finished<1) {}
```

I have tried adding a different number of parameters to the function being passed into the then function. I have also tried adding a finally block. comments show that the async call is successful and successfully returning, so I can't fathom what the problem is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `while (finished<1) {}` is an infinite loop that will never terminate, blocking the event loop and preventing the fetch from occurring. `finished++` is not going to be executed "in the background" or "in parallel".

Comment: "*It doesn't seem to call the then function after being resolved. Therefore, it doesn't increment the flag and it gets stuck in the infinite loop.*" - you've got the causality inverted. It gets stuck in the infinite loop, *therefore* it never calls the function and increments the flag.

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to do asynchronous action inside the `render` method.
Most of your get data API calls should be done inside the `componentDidMount`.

Your render method always should be more concerned about returning UI.
Render methods should be pure, it's mean that it only uses state and props to render, never try to modify the state or do any other actions in render.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { data: null }
  }
  

  async componentDidMount() {
    const apiData = await fetch();
    const jsoned = await apiData.json();
    this.setState({ data: jsoned });
  } 

  render() {
    if (!data) return null;

    return (
      <div>
        {data.map()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have an infinite loop that waits until the call finishes. Also, I have the same problem when I try to do an asynchronous call in componentDidMount. Also, the reason why I have this in the render function is because I want to make it stateless (or at least not have the data stored in a state). Is this bad practice?

Comment: React is based on `state`. In order for data to show on that page, you have to put it in `state`. Post your code with the infinite loop?

Comment: I have the infinite loop in my original post. I basically wait for a variable to increment before moving on. That variable only gets incremented in the then method. My problem is that the function that is passed to then never gets called even after the fetch is complete. The server side logging shows that it successfully handled the fetch call but the fetch call doesn't seem to call the then function after being resolved. Therefore, it doesn't increment the flag and it gets stuck in the infinite loop.